# Moving Ubuntu to a new hdd

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, files, hard-drive, clipboard

I have a 300gb hdd which I am currently using on my older PC. Now I want to have a copy of those 300GB into a new 1TB hdd (installed in a new computer).

My "problem" is that the 1TB hdd already has a 50GB partition with a Win XP (the rest of the space is not partitioned).

The 300GB disk has a 240GB partition for Ubuntu, and the rest is a FAT partition which I don't care if it gets copied or not to the new disk.

So how can I transfer the entire Ubuntu to the new hard disk and still being able to boot the XP?

Is there a way or tool that can help me do over LAN? So I wont have to take out the hdd from the new pc and put it in the older to do the copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the application you're looking for is [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php). It can clone partitions or entire disks preserving the boot options.